# Agregar objeto en un arreglo del state desde un form - React JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, reactjs, redux, react-redux

El problema es que puedo incertar bien los strings en el state desde el formulario, pero cuando se trata de un arreglo que espera un objeto, no puedo incertar el dato.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class CrearPropiedad extends Component {
    state = { 
        nombre : '',
        desarrollador : '',
        ambientes : '',
        direccion : '',
        barrio : '',
        localidad : '',
        provincia : '',
        avancedeobra : '',
        preciodesde : '',
        descripcion : '',
        slug : '',
        tipopropiedad : '',
        videos : '',
        amenities : [],
        consultas : [],
        coordenadas : {},
        imagenes : [],
        planos : [],
        unidades : [],
    }

    //Extrae los valores del input y los coloca en el state
        leerDato = e => {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name] : e.target.value
            })
        }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 mb-4">
                    <Link to={'/admin'}>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" >Volver al Listado</Button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
<div className="col-12">
    <h2>Nueva Propiedad</h2>

    <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-8 mt-5">
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Nombre:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='nombre'
                    placeholder='Nombre de la propiedad'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.nombre}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Desarrollador:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='desarrollador'
                    placeholder='Nombre del desarrollador'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.desarrollador}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Ambientes:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='ambientes'
                    placeholder='Ambientes'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.ambientes}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Dirección:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='direccion'
                    placeholder='Dirección'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.direccion}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Barrio:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='barrio'
                    placeholder='Barrio'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.barrio}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Localidad:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='localidad'
                    placeholder='Localidad'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.localidad}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Provincia:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='provincia'
                    placeholder='Provincia'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.provincia}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Avance de Obra:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='avancedeobra'
                    placeholder='Avance de Obra'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.avancedeobra}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Precio desde:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='preciodesde'
                    placeholder='Precio'
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.preciodesde}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Descripción:</label>
                    <textarea
                    rows='3'
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='descripcion'
                    placeholder='Descripción'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.descripcion}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Slug:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='slug'
                    placeholder='Slug'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.slug}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Tipo de propiedad:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='tipopropiedad'
                    placeholder='Tipo de propiedad'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.tipopropiedad}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Video:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='videos'
                    placeholder='https://www.youtube.com/embed/DafBUFR-B4E'
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.videos}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Amenities:</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='header'
                    placeholder='Header'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.amenities}
                    />

                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='cuerpo'
                    placeholder='Cuerpo'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.amenities}
                    />

                    <input 
                    type='text'
                    className='form-control'
                    name='icono'
                    placeholder='Icono'
                    required
                    onChange={this.leerDato}
                    value={this.state.amenities}
                    />
                </div>

                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" >Crear propiedad</Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default CrearPropiedad;
```

Por ejemplo "amenities" espera arreglos con 3 llaves cada uno:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso hay 2 objetos cargados en la base de datos como ejemplo.

tampoco se como insertar los datos si es un objeto como por ejemplo "coordenadas":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando Firestore para la base de datos y API.
Tambien no puedo definir como agregar mas de un objeto en el arreglo.

Comment: Yo usaría un método para los input que traen Strings y otro distinto para los que tienes que construir el arreglo para simplificar.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien tu problema, pero intenta lo siguiente, tal vez es lo que necesitas. Es usar el atributo `data-*`. Si pasas un tipo de datos distinto a `String` tienes que convertirlo a String y luego a su valor original. Esto es fácil con `JSON.stringify` y `JSON.parse` si estás trabajando con Arrays u Objetos

```
const leerDato = e => {
   e.persist();

   this.setState({
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value || JSON.parse(e.target.data.value)
   });
};

<input
   type='text'
   className='form-control'
   name='header'
   placeholder='Header'
   required
   onChange={this.leerDato}
   data-value={JSON.stringify(this.state.amenities)}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que estás usando la misma función para tratar los `string` y los `arrays`, te sugiero lo siguiente:

crea un nueva función que maneje las lista, la puedes llamar `leerListaDatos` (p.e.)

```
leerListaDatos = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
        [name] : [...this.state[name], e.target.value],
    })
}
```

Ahora a los input que manejan string les debes pasar la función `leerDato`, mientras que a la que maneja arrays le pasas `leerDatos`.

Pero ojo que `coordenadas` espera un objeto, por lo que debes tratarlo de diferente forma:

```
leerObjetoDatos = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
        [name] : {...this.state[name], e.target.value},
    })
}
```